# Can't locate output affecting HTML and file output

Tags: php, html, laravel

Below are screenshots of the output within Chrome dev tools, and one of my controller methods.

The second screenshot is of an empty controller that simply `die();`'s.

The third is the controller that is outputting the second image.

[image: Screenshot of HTML output]

[image: Screenshot of blank output]

[image]

I've trawled all files in my app in an attempt to locate the cause of the erroneous output, with no success.

It *appears* to be an accidentally commented `<?php` tag, but I can't see how that would cause the doctype error?

I should note that this is happening *globally*, and I've already checked my existing doctype declaration and opening php tags.

At my wit's end, thanks for any help.

Comment: can you show your blade file

Comment: @HoàngĐăng The blade file for the first screenshot starts explicitly with ```<!DOCTYPE html>```. The second one has no blade file.

Comment: you are using laravel 5 right?

Comment: @HoàngĐăng Yes, 5.4.23.

Comment: if call `die()` nothing will return. anything wrong in your route?

Comment: I appreciate the effort, but it was caused by an empty PHP file with only ```<?php``` in it and nothing else.

Comment: your route like this `Route::get('/{id}/{id2}','testController@index');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out the extra output was caused by an empty `Helper` file, that only contained `<?php` and nothing else.

This appears to have resulted in the `<?php` not being parsed *as* PHP, and output as text in an HTML comment somewhere down the line.

Answer (score -1):

try to remove the comment 
and i you want use php comment it should be inside php tags

```
<?php /* comment */ ?>
```

and if you want use html comment it should be inside html tags

```
<html>
<!--comment  -->
</html>
```

Comment: if it's comment it wouldn't show in the browser
put mouse over that comment and try to fix it using inspect and to make it like i told you 
if it works go to source in inspect and find where the code is

Comment: While this make no sense, I attempted to reformat within inspector anyway.

Changing ```<!--?php<!DOCTYPE html-->``` to ```<!DOCTYPE html>``` just removes all content within the page, and resets it back to ```<!--?php<!DOCTYPE html-->``` anyway.